# What could be a good loop invariant for this?

Tags: algorithms, loop-invariants

I am currently new and learning about loop invariants. I have come across this pseudocode where the goal is to shift the elements inside an array with ***N*** size in a clockwise direction by ***K*** steps.

Pseudocode:

> [image: Pseudocode]

Is `at every iteration, new_index is in [0,N)` a good loop invariant? I am really confused about how to pick a good one. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would not be a good loop invariant, since its trivial (by the definition of modolu).

A good loop invariant here would be to assert that at step $m$, $A_{rot}$ will contain the first $m$ elements after rotation.

This loop invariant is *not* trivial anymore (you will need to work a bit to prove it) - and using it when $m=N$ will immediately prove that the algorithm is correct.

Comment: This makes much more sense. Thank you!

Comment: @fynn Glad I can help! In general, you would want to find loop invariants in such a way that on the last iteration the loop invariant will conclude that the entire property holds. That is, you want to use the loop invariant to prove correctness - so choose your loop invariant to reflect this.